# Python: How can I group this list of items by category?

Tags: python, django

Working with a Django app. I have a List of `ads` and I want to be able to filter on these in templates (eg, grab all ads of `spot_id = 1`, then pick a random one.

I'm using raw SQL via the cursor instead of Django's mysterious querying, so I already have my list (converted into a dict). Here's what I have so far:

```
# list/dict of ads
[
 {'filename': u'rc_ad_06_02_11.gif', 'spot_id': 1L }, 
 {'filename': u'k_banner.jpg', 'spot_id': 1L}, 
 {'filename': u'dwarves-banner.gif', 'spot_id': 1L}, 
 {'filename': u'k_skyscraper.jpg', 'spot_id': 2L }
]   

# attempt to group them somehow
final_ads = []

    last_spot_id = 0
    for a in ads:
        if a['spot_id'] != last_spot_id:
        final_ads[a['spot_id']][] = a # syntax error here
    last_spot_id = a['spot_id']

logger.info(final_ads)
```

This doesn't work. What I'm essentially trying to get to is a list of this kind of structure:

```
[
 1: [
     {'filename': u'rc_ad_06_02_11.gif', 'spot_id': 1L }, 
     {'filename': u'k_banner.jpg', 'spot_id': 1L}, 
     {'filename': u'dwarves-banner.gif', 'spot_id': 1L}
 ],
 2: [
     {'filename': u'k_skyscraper.jpg', 'spot_id': 2L }
 ]
]
```

(couldn't think of a proper way of representing this, sorry if it doesn't look right).

If anyone can show me a smarter way of doing this I'd be very appreciative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this script is what you're looking for.

```
final_ads = {}
for a in ads:
    final_ads.setdefault(a['spot_id'], []).append(a)
```

Note `setdefault` that initializes the list if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Lots of good answers here but accepting this one as it's closest to the spirit of what I was trying to do (great tip on `setdefault`, was struggling with how to achieve that dynamically).

Answer (score 2):

defaultdict should handle this nice it will return a dict rather than a list

final_ads will be something like {1:[a1,a3,a4],2:[a2,a5]...}

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_ads = defaultdict(list)
for a in ads:
    final_ads[a['spot_id']].append(a)

print final_ads
for spot_id in sorted(final_ads.keys()):
    print "Spot %s=%s"%(spot_id,final_ads[spot_id])
```

above code with your list of dicts <s>returns</s> prints

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1L: [{'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'rc_ad_06_02_11.gif'}, {'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'k_banner.jpg'}, {'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'dwarves-banner.gif'}], 2L: [{'spot_id': 2L, 'filename': u'k_skyscraper.jpg'}]})
Spot 1=[{'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'rc_ad_06_02_11.gif'}, {'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'k_banner.jpg'}, {'spot_id': 1L, 'filename': u'dwarves-banner.gif'}]
Spot 2=[{'spot_id': 2L, 'filename': u'k_skyscraper.jpg'}]
```

Comment: Does it deal well with `long` such as `1L`?

Comment: sure its a dict ... 1L will probably down cast to 1 ... (or not see results above..its still 1L)

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
final_ads = collections.defaultdict(list)
for ad in ads:
    final_ads[ad['spot_id']].append(ad)
logger.info(final_ads)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
grps = itertools.groupby(ads,lambda x:x['spot_id'])
final_ads = dict(map(lambda (k,g):(k,list(g)),grps)
```